# GridFSDBFile cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I'm coding a spring mvc webapp that uses images of type `MultipartFile` which i convert to `byte[]` and then to `Inputstream` and store it in **MongoDB** using `GridFsTemplate`.

Now the problem is I want to display the stored images in a webpage but whenever I try to, the database returns the image file as `GridFSDBFiles` and so tosses the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

This is my DAO for storing images:

```
public void saveScan(Scan scan) throws IOException {

    String owner = String.valueOf(scan.getPatientId());

    String fileName = String.valueOf(scan.getPatientId() + "" + scan.getScanType());

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm a");
    String uploadTime = simpleDateFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println("the scan type is " + scan.getScanType());

    DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();

    metaData.put("owner", owner);
    metaData.put("fileName", fileName);
    metaData.put("uploadTime", uploadTime);

    byte[] scanBytes = scan.getScan().getBytes();
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(scanBytes);
    scanDaoImpl.SaveScan(inputStream, fileName, "image/jpeg", metaData);
}
```

And this is for retrieving the images:

```
public MultipartFile findOneScan(BigInteger patientId) {

    MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile) gridFsTemplate
            .findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("metadata.owner").is(patientId)));
    return multipartFile;
```

And this is my controller for getting images

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{id}/scan", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> scanImage(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id) throws IOException {

    logger.debug("scanImage() is finding Image to display");

    byte[] bs = patientScanServiceImpl.findOne(id).getBytes();

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bs, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is my thymeleaf image tag:

```
<span>
    <img th:src="@{/patients/{patientid}/scan(patientid=${patient.id})}" width="250" height="250"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have more insight in this, and I have finally found a solution. You cannot directly cast a **gridFSDBFile** straight to **byte[ ]**; it must first be converted to **OutputStream** and then **byte[ ]** if it must be displayed. So I allowed my DAO method to return a **GridFSDBFile** but in the service layer I converted the **GridFSDBFile** to **ByteArrayOutputStream** and then to **byte[ ]**. 
Now my DAO method for retrieving images is

```
public GridFSDBFile findOneScan(BigInteger patientId, String scanType) {

    String fileName = String.valueOf(patientId + "" + scanType);

    GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("metadata.fileName").is(fileName)));
    return gridFSDBFile;
```

And my service layer which feeds the controller is

```
public byte[] findOne(BigInteger patientId, String scanType) throws IOException {

    GridFSDBFile gridFSDBFile = scanRepository.findOneScan(patientId, scanType);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    gridFSDBFile.writeTo(outputStream);
    byte[] bs = outputStream.toByteArray();

    return bs;
}
```

And the whole thing works fine.